# Using pedal switch in Ableton

Tags: guitar, recording, guitar-effects, ableton-live

I have the Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 sound card and Orange FS-1 foot switch from my Orange amp. I use Ableton Live for recording my guitar.

My question is, can I connect the pedal to the other input on the sound card and use it to control effects in Ableton? How?

Comment: You need to connect the foot switch to something that will send MIDI messages, either directly over USB or wifi or through the Scarlett interface. Many USB midi keyboards have a foot switch input that you can map in Live. Also some dedicated Live controllers (Push for certain) have foot switch jacks.

Answer (score 1):

As Tood Wilcox mentioned, I also use a footswitch connected to my Ableton Push to control track record/start/stop so I can play and record guitar without having to use the mouse/keyboard.

But if you don't want to buy an additional Push/Keyboard/MIDI device to use with your FS-1, you can get a standalone footswitch that plugs directly into your computer via USB. Search for "USB MIDI footswitch". There are plenty of options. Most of them have a few different switches, but in Ableton you can map any MIDI input from a device like this to any number of parameters.

It looks like your Scarlett doesn't have direct MIDI input, so if you can't find a USB MIDI device, you can also use regular MIDI device with an inexpensive MIDI>USB adapter (about $20). One popular MIDI pedal is the [Behringer FCB1010](http://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Accessories/Midi-Foot-Controllers/FCB1010/p/P0089), though it's about $150. There are cheaper options as well.